# Simultaneous AsyncTasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask, okhttp

I am developing an android app that has to do multiple simultaneous http requests to the server so I decided to use the okhttp library to make the requests.

The problem is that when I try to make some request simultaneously, I have to wait until the first finishes, to perform the following.

I am creating and running AsyncTasks from which I call the following methods:

```
public class ApiRestClient {

    public static void get(String url, Map<String, String> params, Api.ApiCallback callback) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

        try {
            HttpUrl.Builder builder = HttpUrl.parse(url).newBuilder();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : params.entrySet()) {
                builder.addQueryParameter(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
            }

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(builder.build())
                    .get()
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if (response.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                if (callback != null) {
                    try {
                        try {
                            callback.onSuccess(data);
                        } catch (JSONException ex){
                            throw new ApiException(data, ex);
                        }
                    } catch (ApiException ex) {
                        callback.onFail(ex);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (callback != null) {
                    callback.onFail(new ApiException(response.code()));
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
            Log.e(ApiRestClient.class.getSimpleName(), "ApiRestClient.get", e);
            if (callback != null) {
                callback.onFail(new ApiException(ApiException.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,e));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void post(String url, Map<String, String> params, Api.ApiCallback callback) {
        try {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

            HttpUrl.Builder builder = HttpUrl.parse(url).newBuilder();

            FormBody.Builder formBuilder = new FormBody.Builder();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : params.entrySet()) {
                formBuilder.add(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
            }

            RequestBody body = formBuilder.build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(builder.build())
                    .post(body)
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if (response.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                if (callback != null) {
                    try {
                        callback.onSuccess(data);
                    } catch (ApiException ex){
                        callback.onFail(ex);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (callback != null) {
                    callback.onFail(new ApiException(response.code()));
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
            Log.e(ApiRestClient.class.getSimpleName(), "ApiRestClient.post", e);
            if (callback != null) {
                callback.onFail(new ApiException(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR,e));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the AsyncTask code:

```
public class ApiMethods extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {

    private RequestMethod requestMethod;
    private String serverURL;
    private Api.ApiCallback callback;
    private Map<String, String> requestParams;
    public ApiMethods(RequestMethod requestMethod, String serverURL, Map<String, String> requestParams, Api.ApiCallback callback) {
        this.requestMethod = requestMethod;
        this.serverURL = serverURL;
        this.callback = callback;
        this.requestParams = requestParams;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        switch (this.requestMethod) {
            case GET:
                ApiRestClient.get(serverURL, requestParams, callback);
                break;

            case POST:
                ApiRestClient.post(serverURL, requestParams, callback);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public enum RequestMethod {
        GET, POST
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `AsyncTask` docs:

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke `executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[])` with `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.

So if you had

```
        ApiMethods apiMethods = new ApiMethods();
```

Change

```
        apiMethods.execute(params);
```

to

```
        apiMethods.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
```

From the `executeOnExecutor` doc:

> *Warning:* Allowing multiple tasks to run in parallel from a thread pool is generally not what one wants, because the order of their operation is not defined. For example, if these tasks are used to modify any state in common (such as writing a file due to a button click), there are no guarantees on the order of the modifications. Without careful work it is possible in rare cases for the newer version of the data to be over-written by an older one, leading to obscure data loss and stability issues. Such changes are best executed in serial; to guarantee such work is serialized regardless of platform version you can use this function with SERIAL_EXECUTOR.